# two different apks for two apps from one manifest file with two launcher activities

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to build two apps which need to coexist, one of the apps is a client app and the other a merchant.
Is it possible generating two different apks from one manifest file with two launcher activities?
Just like uber

Comment: Most of the time I see that **Question is too broad**. Here your example - `Just like uber` is **too borad**.

Comment: https://github.com/bmorelli25/Simple-Android-Uber-Clone

Comment: Check out that sample link I am trying to build two apps in one project with two apks for either the client or merchant to download